# explode() doesn't separate a string by spaces?

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents, explode

I am attempting to open a text file and explode the list of names within into an array but when I `var_dump` the new array I get this:

`array(1) { [0]=> string(61) "name name name name " }`

The entire contents of the list goes into one single key field in the array.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$ingame_list = file_get_contents('../../../../home/folder/folder/list.txt');
$newarray = explode(" ", $ingame_list);
var_dump($newarray);
```

How can I get each name to be in its own key field within the new array?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the text file

Comment: Ever thought about using a format especially designed for structured data like JSON, XML, YAML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr** Your list is separated by something other than simple spaces - most likely multiple adjacent whitespace characters. You're actually seeing an HTML rendering of the data, in which multiple adjacent whitespace characters are displayed as one.

Note the `string(61)` in the results of `var_dump()`.  `var_dump()` reports the type, length, and content of a variable (in the case of a string). That `string(61)` means there are 61 characters in your string. So, if you are really getting back the string `"name name name name "`, this implies there are characters that you are not seeing here. This could be because of the way whitespace displays in HTML: tabs, newlines, and other whitespace characters all look like simple spaces.  Are you sure the text is separated by spaces, not tabs or other whitespace?

`explode()` will only split the string on exact matches to the specified character/string. If the text is separated by `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, or other non-printing characters, your `explode()` statement won't work.  For example, if you have this:

```
name    name    name
```

(pretend those are tab characters above), then your `explode()` doesn't find any plain old space (, character value 32) characters.

**How to Fix This**

Based on your comments below, your data contains newline (`\n`) characters, not plain spaces. You need to replace the second line of your code with this:

```
$newarray = explode("\n", $ingame_list);
```

Comment: Well in the list they are seperated by line breaks!

Comment: Well, there you go! :)

Comment: @crm line break is not `" "`. Try `"\n"`

Comment: @crm: Even easier, no explode needed. `file()`

Answer (score 2):

If they are separated by newlines then you don't even need explode:

```
$newarray = file('../../../../home/folder/folder/list.txt');
```